# Wordpress: Using it as a news CMS only?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried to search everywhere for an answer to my question but I still doesn't understand how Wordpress fully work.

I would like to use Wordpress as my news system CMS only. This means, I do not wish to set up my page layout via the Wordpress theme interface. If you guys know another news CMS called CuteNews, I want my Wordpress to operate pretty much like CuteNews.

How can I put Wordpress post entries into my website that uses my own layout (and not using the theme interface in Wordpress).

Thanks!

Comment: just don't touch the theming system? Is there any real problem to be solved here? I'm guessing you have an XY problem.

Comment: Sorry if you feel that your time is wasted here. I haven't personally install Wordpress yet because I am afraid it might affect my current live website which uses CuteNews. Do note that I am not an advanced web builder or anything, I am just a novice and making web layout and getting things to work is my hobby.

Just want to get some confirmation on this. Thanks for answering me.

Comment: you can install WordPress to a local web server, such as XAMPP, if you're worried of the possible effect of installing to the live server to your existing website.

Comment: I will look into that thanks. Sorry but does anyone have a link to show me how can I pull the blog entries of my Wordpress to my web layout?

Comment: you want to show wordpress posts on your existing layout? if that is what you looking for, please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241327/pull-content-from-wordpress-site-to-display-on-html-site/)

Answer (score 1):

For people looking at this from google. Check out this blog post
http://sidigital.co/blog/disconnect-your-frontend-from-wordpress

I have used this as a starting point for my detached wordpress site and it's working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually! Without converting it to a theme. It works for me as I don't do wordpress themes but I use WP to power the back-end of my websites. I utilize WP's CMS feature.

here's a checklist of what you can possibly do to your website.

1. Your website design (html/css)
2. Install Wordpress on your server, or locally.
3. Download Blank WP Template, set this as your default template for your wordpress site.
4. Edit the Theme's CSS/Header/Footer according to your website design while keeping essential WP codes provided in the template.
5. Set your News Page as the Blog Entry in WP Dashboard.
6. If you want some news preview, such as titles to appear somewhere on your site like homepage, you can either call it thru PHP code available on the net or install a plugin in WP.

Items listed above maybe broad, but that's a starting point, as you can research on the net for detailed information on how to go about your website with wordpress CMS.

Best of Luck!